# How can i know who has created user?

Tags: users

I have created some roles and these role's user also can create certain type of user.so how to know who is creator i.e, user author name.

Answer (score 1):

By default Drupal don't save anything about who create a user.
If you want do it, go to user account fields  `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` add entity_reference with select list widget, then in your custom module in `hook_form_alter` set default value for field with get current user uid and then hide it there, in this manner the current user id (the user that create user) saved in fields without he/she know that this, also you can dont use `hook_form_alter` just get `$user->uid`(the current user that create user ) form global $user in `hook_user_insert`

shortly

- add a entity reference field to user save creator uid in
- `hook_form_alter` when or `hook_user_insert`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new text/entity_reference field in User and save current user in hook_user_presave.